# Washing Machine Fills with water, then drains

Tags: washing-machine

We have a front loading GE washing machine model GFWN1000. Recently, when running any of the wash cycles, it will fill with water like normal and then go ahead and drain without doing any washing.

I tested the spin functionality, and it works fine on a drain and spin cycle. The agitation functionality appears to be what is not happening.

I've checked that there's no siphoning, the load is balanced (by using a small load of shirts), and the pump filter is not clogged.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Does it fill and then drain right away? Or does it wait the normal wash time and then drain?

Comment: It drains right after filling. Then it unlocks the door and goes into paused state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the water inlet valve, where the water flows into the washer. The water was flowing too slowly. After 8 minutes of fill time, the system drains and then pauses, since there must be some issue if it takes that long.

I replaced it and the water flowed very fast, filling enough water for the wash cycle in about a minute.

I followed this video on how to remove the top of the washer, unhook the water inlet valve, hook up the new one, and then put everything back the way it was. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rIeWi6sm0Q

Here is a picture of the General Electric WH13X10029 Water Inlet Valve I used:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also check the water fill hose. Some of them have a screen to trap particles. If the screen is dirty, it will slow the water flow as well causing the machine to "time out"  and go directly to drain.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a possible issue with the logic controller circuit. Either the controller is simply malfunctioning or another issue has tripped an error code in the control Unit. Unplug the washer from the wall, wait 15 seconds, then plug it back in and start a load cycle from the beginning. I will need more info to further diagnose the issue.

- Did you lose power or unplug the machine during a wash cycle?
- Is the hot water supply adequate, sometimes auto temperature controls prevent the wash cycle from running at an incorrect temperature.
- Check to make sure the detergent dispenser is not clogged.
- Make sure the door latch engages properly, my washer would fill with water and then do nothing because the door closed switch was broken. This is a safety feature.
- Try selecting the extra rinse option and running a regular wash cycle. Does the washer drain and refill twice or just end the cycle?
- Try running a **basket clean** cycle to see if that alleviates and build up of residue inside the drum that could be causing issues.
- The only other issue I can think of is that the load sensor has malfunctioned and is reporting incorrect data to the controller.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to unplug for 15 seconds and see if that works. To answer your questions: maybe lost peer; hot water is adequate (hasn’t changed); no clog; latch works. I will reply with the results of your suggestions.

Comment: That sounds like logic controller circuit to me too. All the suggestions listed make sense, except the door latch - if the door latch wasn't working properly then you shouldn't get a drain/spin.

Comment: Unplugging for 15 or more seconds doesn't appear to alter its behavior in any way. I ran basket clean, but it didn't make a difference when running a wash cycle afterwards. If it is a logic controller circuit, is that something I can buy and replace myself? Would it be one of the parts on this page? https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/ModelSectionParts/GFWN1000L0WW/1/0/0/0/CONTROLS_&_DISPENER

Answer (score 1):

Another answer by Olivier VH refers to a possible issue, but uses vague terms, so I’m posting a more complete answer as I had the same issue.

I have a Kenmore/GE model 2130 top load washing machine.  When you remove the control panel (the part with all of the dials and buttons) on the top to check the items inside, you might accidentally detach the pressure hose. When the pressure hose is not attached, the washing machine will fill up and then immediately drain without agitating or starting the wash cycle.  It did seem to properly do a spin and drain cycle, though.  Here's a picture of the hose:

[image: Hose coming from main part of washer]

You must attach the hose back to the control panel so that the machine will operate.  Be sure to attach the hose when the washing machine is empty, otherwise the pressure will not work accurately.  Here's a picture of where to attach the hose on my particular machine.

[image: Where to connect hose]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. While this is very helpful information, it doesn't seem to address the original question, as it's about a different model of washing machine. Do you know if this applies to the OP's model, as well? While general comments like this are appropriate at some sites, if you'll take the [tour] and browse the [help], you'll see that they're considered off topic here as we like to keep things as tightly focused on the question at hand as possible. Please [edit] to indicate if this does apply to the OP's model, all GE models, all washers in general, etc.

Comment: @FreeMan While I agree that this does not apply to the OPs exact situation, it was a result of the same symptoms.  I ended up buying a new water inlet valve because of the answer on this question, which was useless because it wasn't the problem and I couldn't find any information anywhere detailing this particular possible cause.  At least one other user had the same issue although answered without enough details.  How should I communicate this information out?

Comment: I have edited to specifically note that this caused the same symptoms as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy thing to try :
I had the same issue.  It happened after I removed the barrel to clean it.  When I remove the head, I pulled out a transparent tube that goes into the head of the machine.  It is some sort of sensor connector.  Once I plugged it back, it stopped draining after filling up.

Comment: Is this for the same model? Is it the same brand? What is "the head"? Some more details will help this answer greatly, otherwise, it's likely to get deleted as it doesn't appear to be very helpful. Please take the [tour] and browse through the [help] (especially the part on answering) to see what we expect in terms of quality at this Question & Answer site.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I had the same problem and was able to fix it in part due to this answer.  Note that I have provided a more detailed answer that describes this issue.